# How to convert Netscape-Bookmark-File-Format into well formed XML to manipulate

Tags: javascript, c#, php, html, xml

I have exported Netscape-Bookmark-Files as .html from Chrome, IE, and Firefox. These files are similar. Is there a way to convert this .html file into well-formed XML, for example, to view it in a TreeView in WPF? Or is there a workaround for that?

Maybe there is a better way to exchange Bookmarks under the Browsers which I don't know. Something like the JSON Files maybe....

I have to do a Project(C#) in which I have to program a little Bookmark Manager which I can Import and Export this HTML files as well as my own Bookmarks which are saved in a Database.... Do you have a better idea for this?

Please help me....

Regards

Comment: Simplest method is to de-serialize json to classes and then serialize classes to xml.  but you do not need xml to take classes and load into a treeview.

Answer (score 0):

Treat each `HTML` `<DT>` tag like a new line.
In whatever language you have access to wrap each new line into a format that `jstree.js` can read so you end up with format as described [here](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/),
or simply use:

```
[{ id:lineCount, text:linedata},{rince and repeat}]
```

Then in whatever page you are using to display your tree load the `json` and you are good to go. Be careful you do not publish it openly as this writer would be concerned about any embeded authorization codes.

Another level of tricky would be to make each heading a parent. So in your preprocess you would create children object according to the above spec. As simple directory like re-entrant method (like you were going through a directory tree) would be able to child each group.

Then you would have

```
[{ id:lineCount, text:linedataParent, children[{id:lineCount, text:child, rince and repeat}, id:lineCount, text:nextParent, children:[{..and so on..}]...}]
```

Resulting in a somewhat nicer `jsTree` with parent/children the way you intended when you did your bookmark management.

Pretty sure this wont get voted best answer but it might be a start for you.

Answer (score -1):

But i dont have JSON Files. I only have this f...ed up Netscape Bookmark File Format to work with. There is no Documentation for this Format. Only a poor one on Microsoft....

Comment: This is not an answer.